# Can sscan detect if a decimal point is accidentally used as a delimiter in a string of floats?

Tags: c

An erroneously placed decimal is not detected. Other input errors cause the count to be incorrect (!= 3).
The following is the simplified example:

````
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include <string.h>   
    #include <stdlib.h>   
    #include <limits.h>   
    #include <math.h>   
    ```
    int main()
    {
         char in[32];
         int count;
         float a, b, c;   /*  sides of triangle   */
         printf("Enter the sides of triangle as numbers with included decimal point\n");
         fgets(in, 31, stdin);
         count = sscanf(in, "%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
             printf("count = %d\n", count);
         printf("you entered %f %f %f\n", a, b, c);
         return(0);
    }
````

If the user enters three numbers separated by spaces it works correctly; if something besides a number is entered the count is wrong. But if two of the numbers are separated by a decimal point such as "2.3.4.6 5.0" the count is correct but the last two floats are incorrect i.e 0.4 and 0.6.

Comment: `.4` and `.6` are valid floating point values according to C and scanf. The final 5.0 isn't parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf` will read from the input until it's pattern no longer matches, and if no recovery is possible. It'll simply stop.

In this case, when you do `%f %f %f` on `2.3.4.6 5.0`, what really happens is this-

- Encounter `2.3` - valid, store into `a`
- Encounter `.4` - valid, store into `b`
- Encounter `.6` - valid, store into `c`

And that's when the `sscanf` stops, because all format specifiers have been extracted.

Now, sanitizing user input is difficult with format strings but in your specific case - it is possible, although hacky.

The format specifier you should use is this - `%f%*[. ]%f%*[. ]%f`

So what does it do?

- `%f` -> Reads a valid float
- `%*[. ]` -> Reads *any number* of - either a decimal point *or* a space - and discards it

I suppose you can see where I'm going with this, this is how the `sscanf` would look like-

`count = sscanf(in, "%f%*[. ]%f%*[. ]%f", &a, &b, &c);`

Now, feed in the inputs!

```
2 3 1
```

You get

```
2.000000 3.000000 1.000000
```

Wait, that doesn't demonstrate anything, how about-

```
2.3.4.6 5.0
```

You get

```
2.300000 4.600000 5.000000
```

Ho, now we're goin somewhere

I sure had my fun with this one, feed in this-

```
256.1450              31.5.6.4
```

You get,

```
256.144989 31.500000 6.400000
```

(don't worry about the rounding, that's how floats are stored in memory)

Not done yet, how about this one-

```
256.1450              31.5.6
```

That doesn't even look like valid floats, is that a date?

```
256.144989 31.500000 6.000000
```

Nope, you can still get floats from that one.

Just so you know, yeah sure you can technically do a whole bunch of hacky pattern matching with `sscanf` but this is really not very practical. I hope this does answer your question, but please, look into iterating through the strings in case you cannot trust the user input.

Unless, you *want* to use hacky stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess I don't understand these format strings any better than some of the more exotic regular expressions. This makes my little program work but I think I'll see if I can do this some other way.